# Реализация удаления временных аккаунтов по истечению их срока действия

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

Решил для интернет-магазина создавать временные аккаунты.
То есть можно зарегистрироваться и заходить в постоянный аккаунт с логином и паролем, указанными при регистрации, а можно просто класть в корзину товары, не регистрируясь.
Для этого у меня создается при первом посещении сайта Guid-строка, которая записывается в куки как UnauthenticatedID. 
Можно было бы просто связать товар в корзине с этим Guid, но там идет привязка по (int)Id пользователя из таблицы Users, поэтому создаются эти самые аккаунты, чтобы не создавать новых колонок.
У аккаунтов, как и у самих куков, есть Expiration Date = 14 дней с момента регистрации. Отсюда вопрос: как мне лучше реализовать автоматическую ежедневную проверку на наличие истекших аккаунтов и их удаления? 
Если непонятно объяснил, что я и подозреваю, могу что-то дополнить

Comment: Создаёте поле в таблице аккаунтов типа TIMESTAMP с названием last_active и добавляете cron скрипт с запуском раз в день для удаления записей у которых дата последнего посещения раньше чем текущая минус 14 дней. Что может быть проще? Товары хранить в куках бессмысленно. Почистил куки и привет. Храните список ID товаров в отдельном поле той же таблицы в строковой переменной вида 222;333;111;777; и при обращении к странице авторизованного пользователя восстанавливайте корзину.

Comment: @Rootware для товаров в корзине у меня отдельная таблица в БД, сами товары в куках не хранятся. Там есть поля Id, ProductId, Quantity, и UserId, где указывается как раз порядковый номер пользователя из таблицы Users

Answer (score 2, accepted):

почему просто не сделать продажу без регистрации?

но если обязательно нужно, то логика такая:

- создаем обычный аккаунт, но втихую, в любое из полей, например имя, пишем timestamp, в логин вписываем что-то типа tempUser
- при регистрации нового аккаунта в конец скрипта добавляем еще один запрос к БД - очистку таблицы исходя из timestamp+2 недели для всех пользователей tempUser, получается новый пользователь добавляется и одновременно устаревшие удаляются

Comment: Ну в данный момент у меня получается пользователь с логином = Guid, паролем = Guid (хэшированный), Имя = Temporary, Фамилия = Temporary, Expiration Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(14) (или как-то так, не помню функцию сейчас). Не очень понимаю, какой именно скрипт вставлять. Есть какой-то способ выполнить функцию при наступлении даты? Ну и нужно учитывать, что не все темпы будут удаляться в один день, а каждый в свой день в зависимости от дня "регистрации". Чтобы корзина две недели хранилась, но не больше

Comment: Есть, средствами сервера, но мой вариант проще. Поверьте, я работал с таким, этот вариант оптимальный. Если люди делают покупки постоянно (регистрируются), то и старый аккаунты будут удаляться постоянно. Не стоит изобретать велосипед, более того, если слишком влезть в отлаженный скрипт, есть вероятность собственной ошибки =)

Comment: Простите. Я верю Вашему опыту, просто немного не понимаю, в чем собственно состоит вариант, что за очистка таблицы? Ну, имею в виду, как это реализуется

Comment: Смотрите, человек в комментарии к вопросу предложил настроить автоматизацию и раз в сутки чистить базу - это вариант. Т.е. нужно чтобы был код, который включается в определенное время и удаляет устаревших пользователей. Я же предлагаю встроить этот код в скрипт регистрации. Т.е. 1 дополнительный запрос к БД, который удаляет всех временных пользователей, которые совершали покупку более 2 недель назад.

Comment: Вы пишите "для товаров в корзине у меня отдельная таблица в БД, сами товары в куках не хранятся. Там есть поля Id, ProductId, Quantity, и UserId, где указывается как раз порядковый номер пользователя из таблицы Users "... ну так тут еще вариант решения: если скрипт не слишком мудреный, то просто передайте в эту таблицу заглушку UserId=0 при добавлении заказа. Я писал магазины с оформлением без регистрации еще лет 8-9 назад, это так и делалось.

Answer (score 2):

Если вам нужно делать что-то по расписанию - лучше сделать отдельный job (консольку) и дергать ее извне по расписанию. Скорее всего ваш хостер поддерживает jobs (на Azure это webjobs, в k8s - cron jobs).

Если хостер джобы не поддерживает - и нужно обойтись только средствами asp.net core - попробуйте выполнять чистку через [Quartz.NET](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/). Не так надежно и предсказуемо, как отдельным job-ом, но лучше, чем ничего.

---

Совсем альтернативный вариант - не чистить вообще. Если на сайте не сверхпосещаемость - никаких проблем не будет. Даже наоборот, когда созреете делать аналитику по юзерам - у вас будут готовые данные :)

Comment: Благодарю за идею, пока сделал консольное приложение, работающее с БД и завел его в Task Scheduler. Остальное пока не умею, да и проект нигде не опубликованный, чисто учусь на нем